# Android NDK: Passing data from Java to C++/C

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native

I have already tried NDK simple examples such as displaying data from a native code to android's java code such as this:

```
 #include <jni.h>

 extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_JNIActivity_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                              jobject thiz )
 {
   return env->NewStringUTF("I'm C++! What the hell am I doing here in android?!");
 }

 }
```

However, I want an application wherein user will have to enter data from a textfield and have this data be pass from it's java code to the native code where calculations will be done. How will I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your Java native method, include a formal String argument that accepts the textfield value.

In C/C++, access the characters from the jstring with JNI methods like these:

```
 jsize GetStringLength(JNIEnv *env, jstring string);
 const jchar * GetStringChars(JNIEnv *env, jstring string, jboolean *isCopy);
 const char * GetStringUTFChars(JNIEnv *env, jstring string, jboolean *isCopy);
```

When you're done with the characters, be sure to release them.

```
 void ReleaseStringChars(JNIEnv *env, jstring string, const jchar *chars);
 void ReleaseStringUTFChars(JNIEnv *env, jstring string, const char *utf);
```

See the [documentation for these methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#string_operations) in the [Java Native Interface Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html).